# expo-device returns null on standalone app

Tags: android, expo, sentry

I'm using Expo in managed workflow for android.

I'm using sentry-expo and I want to log the device info (model, OS version, brand, etc) for the crashes. I noticed that Sentry dashboard logs everything correctly except for the device info (it says Unknown Device - Unknown OS) on standalone app, but on Expo Go it logs everything fine.

As an alternative i tried to use expo-device module, and use some data like:

```
import * as Device from 'expo-device';

alert(Device.brand + ' ' + Device.modelName + ' ' + Device.osName + ' ' + Device.osVersion);
```

All of these work fine IF i'm using Expo Go. But when I build a standalone app, ALL of these return null (tested on different Android phones).

So I'm wondering, why device info can be accessed if project is running on Expo Go, but nothing is accessed on standalone apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this also happened to me!

After you run `yarn add expo-device`
You also need to run `npx pod-install`

If everything has been linked correctly, you should see an Dependency being installed:
`Installing EXDevice (2.4.0)`

Re-build your App and you should now see the device info as expected.